# cannot start chrome browser - bind failed: Permission denied

Tags: udev, chrome, socket, browser, grsecurity

I am using `grsecurity` kernel with `CONFIG_GRKERNSEC_SOCKET_SERVER` enabled:

```
[*] Socket restrictions  
  [ ]   Deny any sockets to group (NEW)  
  [ ]   Deny client sockets to group (NEW)
  [*]   Deny server sockets to group
```

This prevents a user from creating a "server" socket (i.e. starting Apache), but allows opening client sockets (i.e. Firefox).

Indeed, all network clients work fine (Firefox, telnet, ssh, nc, w3m, ..). Only Chrome browser (Chromium) does not work.

When starting chrome from command line,  I get following error:

```
ERROR:address_tracker_linux.cc(138)] Could not bind NETLINK socket: Permission denied
libudev: udev_monitor_enable_receiving: bind failed: Permission denied
FATAL:udev_linux.cc(31)] Check failed: 0 == ret (0 vs. -1)
Aborted
```

and in the logs, I see:

```
grsec: denied bind() by /usr/lib/chromium/chromium[NetworkChangeNo:3920]
grsec: denied bind() by /usr/lib/chromium/chromium[WorkerPool/3922:3922]
grsec: denied bind() by /usr/lib/chromium/chromium[Chrome_IOThread:3934]
grsec: denied bind() by /usr/lib/chromium/chromium[NetworkChangeNo:3966]
grsec: denied bind() by /usr/lib/chromium/chromium[WorkerPool/3968:3968]
grsec: denied bind() by /usr/lib/chromium/chromium[Chrome_IOThread:3980]
```

Can somebody please explain, why chrome fails to start while all other clients (Firefox) work fine ?

I am using Chrome (Chromium) 37 on Debian Wheezy (64-bit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chromium fails to start because denying server sockets also denies `AF_NETLINK` sockets, and for some reason Chromium needs to communicate with `udev`, which required `AF_NETLINK` sockets. I don't have an obviously authoritative source, but I'll try to explain from first principles using the underlying source code and hopefully not make too many mistakes in the process.

I started off investigating the first error message. The code that produces the error message in Chromium is https://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/net/base/address_tracker_linux.cc line 138:

```
  // Request notifications.
  struct sockaddr_nl addr = {};
  addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
  addr.nl_pid = getpid();
  // TODO(szym): Track RTMGRP_LINK as well for ifi_type, http://crbug.com/113993
  addr.nl_groups = RTMGRP_IPV4_IFADDR | RTMGRP_IPV6_IFADDR | RTMGRP_NOTIFY |
      RTMGRP_LINK;
  int rv = bind(netlink_fd_,
                reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr*>(&addr),
                sizeof(addr));
  if (rv < 0) {
    PLOG(ERROR) << "Could not bind NETLINK socket";
    AbortAndForceOnline();
    return;
  }
```

The actual grsec-related failure happens in the `bind()` call, which attempts to set up a netlink socket which will receive notifications whenever an interface IPv4 or IPv6 address changes and whenever a link state changes.

This call is handled by a syscall in the kernel, in [`net/socket.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.18/source/net/socket.c#L1527):

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(bind, int, fd, struct sockaddr __user *, umyaddr, int, addrlen)
{
        struct socket *sock;
        struct sockaddr_storage address;
        int err, fput_needed;
```

This declares the syscall and a few local variables. You can see the syscall declaration matches the `bind()` call in the Chromium code: `int fd, struct sockaddr __user * umyaddr, int addrlen`.

```
        sock = sockfd_lookup_light(fd, &err, &fput_needed);
        if (sock) {
```

This looks the socket up from the file descriptor. If a socket is found...

```
                err = move_addr_to_kernel(umyaddr, addrlen, &address);
                if (err >= 0) {
```

This copies the data provided from user space to kernel space. If there is no error...

```
                        err = security_socket_bind(sock,
                                                   (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                                                   addrlen);
                        if (!err)
```

This gives any loaded LSM (SELinux etc.) a chance to check the call is allowed. If so...

```
                                err = sock->ops->bind(sock,
                                                      (struct sockaddr *)
                                                      &address, addrlen);
```

The bind proceeds elsewhere, and we're done as far as the analysis of the standard kernel code is concerned here.

grsec patches `net/socket.c` in a number of places; in particular, before the LSM security check, it adds its own checks (see https://grsecurity.net/test/grsecurity-3.0-3.18.6-201502062100.patch; search for `SYSCALL_DEFINE3(bind`):

```
                        if (gr_handle_sock_server((struct sockaddr *)&address)) {
                                err = -EACCES;
                                goto error;
                        }
                        err = gr_search_bind(sock, (struct sockaddr_in *)&address);
                        if (err)
                                goto error;
```

The first check is the one that's relevant here; it calls `gr_handle_sock_server()`:

```
gr_handle_sock_server(const struct sockaddr *sck)
{
#ifdef CONFIG_GRKERNSEC_SOCKET_SERVER
       if (grsec_enable_socket_server &&
           in_group_p(grsec_socket_server_gid) &&
           sck && (sck->sa_family != AF_UNIX) &&
           (sck->sa_family != AF_LOCAL)) {
               gr_log_noargs(GR_DONT_AUDIT, GR_BIND_MSG);
               return -EACCES;
       }
#endif
       return 0;
}
```

This implements the "deny server sockets to group" check. As verified in the comments, on your system `grsec_enable_socket_server` is 1, so when running as group 1001, the `if` succeeds (`sck->sa_family == AF_NETLINK` in this case), and access is denied.

Going back to the Chromium code, this logs an error message and calls `AbortAndForceOnline()`, which just sets things up so the browser reckons it's online. So this doesn't explain the failure to start.

Before pushing further I attempted to reproduce the failure. To do this, I adapted `authbind` so it would prevent `AF_NETLINK` binds; in `libauthbind.c`, in the `bind()` function I added a `case` to the first `switch`:

```
  case AF_NETLINK:
    puts("Denying AF_NETLINK");
    return -EACCES;
```

Running with the resulting library reproduced the failure:

```
% LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/authbind/libauthbind.so.1 chromium
Denying AF_NETLINK
 [15858:15876:0214/160730:ERROR:address_tracker_linux.cc(154)] Could not bind NETLINK socket: Success
Denying AF_NETLINK
libudev: udev_monitor_enable_receiving: bind failed: No such file or directory
[15858:15890:0214/160730:FATAL:udev_linux.cc(29)] Check failed: 0 == ret (0 vs. -2)
zsh: abort      LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/authbind/libauthbind.so.1 chromium
```

(The strange error messages, "Success" and "No such file directory", occur because I'm not setting `errno`.)

So the abort is indeed related to `bind()`. Checking `udev_linux.cc` line 29 shows

```
  int ret = udev_monitor_enable_receiving(monitor_.get());
  CHECK_EQ(0, ret);
```

`ret` here is negative because `udev_monitor_enable_receiving()` can't bind a netlink socket, and `CHECK_EQ` causes an assertion failure here (see https://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/base/logging.h for the implementation). This produces an abort signal and Chromium quits with an "Aborted" message of some sort, depending on the shell being used.